# Golang - User of package without selector

Tags: go

Please, I searched this a lot and after not been able to find, I am writing and not that I didn't try to search all over first. Couldn't get the right answer. I even tried to check Revel's function and couldn't get the answer from there as well.

When I run this program I get this error for line

```
./test.go:11: use of package http without selector
```

This error points at the line below where I have written

```
*http
```

inside the struct

Confusing part is that with test and dot I even get auto complete with VIM. So I don't know why is the error. Is it that it has to be somewhat like

```
*(net/http)
```

or something like that ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type HandleHTTP struct {
    *http
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Path is %s", r.URL.Path[1:])

}

func main() {

    test := HandleHTTP{}

    test.http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    test.http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could also say what you are trying to do with the `HandleHTTP` struct. It doesn't follow the conventional usage pattern for http servers as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Ray, I am planning to use a go routines with listener for each struct object but on different port

to do that I would require to take this approach else I would get error for having same path for each struct. I don't know if you get me

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12648104/831878

Comment: No, he has simply created a function inside which the actual http.HandleFunc is. Also in struct, he has simply tried to get the data type but not the function.

Comment: That's invalid Go, you cannot assign a package as a member of a struct, the selector in the error message simply means on of net/http's Types, function, etc. like http.ServeMux, or http.Handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have two or more instances serving from different ports you need to spin up two, or more, server. Would something like this, perhaps, work for you?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type HandleHTTP struct {
    http *http.Server
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Path is %s", r.URL.Path[1:])

}

func main() {
    mux1 := http.NewServeMux()
    mux1.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    test1 := HandleHTTP{http:&http.Server{Addr:":8081", Handler:mux1}}

    mux2 := http.NewServeMux()
    mux2.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    test2 := HandleHTTP{http:&http.Server{Addr:":8082", Handler:mux2}}

    // run the first one in a goroutine so that the second one is executed
    go test1.http.ListenAndServe()
    test2.http.ListenAndServe()

}
```